# swift var won't update outside the block

Tags: swift, firebase, xcode8

I've taken the original code from https://www.weheartswift.com/firebase-101/ and edited to fit my needs.

In this view controller i update an image and then, with a button i perform an unwind segue and another view controller call the function updateValues and stores data in firebase.

what is not working is the updateValues function but only for taskImg value, others (taskTitle and taskLat and taskLon works perfectly)

I think that it won't updates because it's inside this code block

#

```
self.storageRef.child(filePath).put(data as Data, metadata: metaData).observe(.success) { (snapshot) in


 self.downloadURL = snapshot.metadata!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString

            completion()

}
```

#

because if i try to change the value of any var from inside it nothing happens, outside of that block it works but obiouvsly i can't because i have to generate dynamically it...

Can someone help me please?

```
func editImage(completion: @escaping callback){



    let resizedImage = resizeImage(image: imagePicked.image!, newWidth: 200)

    var data = NSData()
    // data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagePicked.image!, 0.1)! as NSData
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage!, 0.1)! as NSData





    let filePath = "\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)/Pictures/\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
    let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()

    //store downloadURL
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
    self.storageRef.child(filePath).put(data as Data, metadata: metaData).observe(.success) { (snapshot) in



        //progress upload
        self.storageRef.child(filePath).put(data as Data, metadata: metaData).observe(.progress) { snapshot in
            // Upload reported progress
            if let progress = snapshot.progress {
                let percentComplete = 100.0 * Double(progress.completedUnitCount) / Double(progress.totalUnitCount)
                print("percent \(percentComplete)")
            }
        }
        self.storageRef.child(filePath).put(data as Data, metadata: metaData).observe(.success) { snapshot in
            // Upload completed successfully
            print("success")
        }

        self.storageRef.child(filePath).put(data as Data, metadata: metaData).observe(.failure) { snapshot in

            print(snapshot.error?.localizedDescription ?? "" )
        }


        self.downloadURL = snapshot.metadata!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString

        completion()

        print(self.taskImg,"\"inside editImage function, right value")


    }


}



func updateValues() {
    self.taskTitle = self.titleField.text
    if tapped == true {
        self.taskLat = latitude
        self.taskLon = longitude
    }else{
        //doesn't update location
    }
    self.taskCompleted = self.completedSwitch.isOn

    if tappedpicture == true {

        editImage { self.taskImg = self.downloadURL
            print (self.downloadURL,"\"inside updateValues function, right value")

                     }

        print (self.taskImg,"\"this is where i need it and it's wrong value")


    }else{
        //doesn't update location
    }



}
```

Comment: What is the type of self.taskImg?  Please provide the class definition as well.

Comment: the type of self.taskImg is String

Comment: You should think of the block as a separate function that's getting called in a later run loop cycle after the scope where the print is declared is long out of scope. I would guess if you put a break point on your print line and then one on your assignment (ie.g. `self.taskImg = downloadURL`) you'll see the `print` gets called first. If you call print right after your assignment inside the block, you'll see it gets called with the updated value. What do you want to do with the `taskImg` variable once it has the correct value?

Comment: I don't know definitively but I would suggest your self is pointing at a different self in the block. If you reference the object directly it should help.

Comment: i use it to update a firebase db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the unwind segue occurs before the put data operation completes and the `self.downloadURL` isn't set at the time of reading by the other view controller.

To check this, you could set a breakpoint in the put completion block and one in the destination segue.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrei, i did as you said and yes, unwind occurs before put, how can i change it?

Comment: I think the easiest way can be to call unwind segue after the self.downloadURL is set to the correct value.